# How to disable slash command syntax in Doxygen

Tags: php, php-5.3, doxygen

I've run into a problem with PHP 5.3 namespacing and Doxygen comments.

Example:

```
/**
 * Sample Method
 *
 * @param string $output
 * @return \Project\Lib\Rest
 */
```

Doxygen gives me the following warnings:

```
warning: Found unknown command `\Project'
warning: Found unknown command `\Lib'
warning: Found unknown command `\Rest'
```

What can I do to fix this or turn off \commands and only use @commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping your backslashes, i.e. use

```
/**
 * Sample Method
 *
 * @param string $output
 * @return \\Project\\Lib\\Rest
 */
```

[`\\`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdbackslash) is actually a doxygen command which just prints a backslash.

See also [Documenting PHP with Doxygen: The Pros and Cons](http://technosophos.com/content/documenting-php-doxygen-pros-and-cons):

```
/**
 * Sample Method
 *
 * @param string $output
 * @return Project::Lib::Rest
 */
```

Comment: This isn't so great because then the double-slash will be visible for users who are just reading the source of documentation (e.g. the header file), and it could confuse them.